# Codename1 CSS styling not being applied on device after installing cn1-codescan-lib

Tags: codenameone

[On device, without codescan library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExGw7.jpg)

[On device, with codescan library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKkqV.jpg)

When I install the cn1 codescanner library from the extension or via maven (pom) the css styling is not applied on my device as shown above.
This is just by adding the library without any use of it in my code.
Can someone assist me in why this is happening and how to rectifying this situation?

Device: Samsung J7 Prime

Comment: Can you elaborate more? Are you using the latest codescan library? Do you use CSS for styling? if so how did you style the code? Did you disable native theme inheritance or something like that?

Comment: Not sure what happened, or what I may have done, but it works now without error. I removed all the libraries and reinstalled the codescan lib via codename one extensions. What I noticed while removing libraries, I had to remove libraries from both "External Libraries" and "cn1libs" directory. I'm not sure if this could have been the source of my previous issue.

Comment: Are you using the old ant project structure? I suggest migrating to the maven projects as they are more reliable consistently.

Comment: I've been using only maven.

Comment: My guess is that something broke in the CSS merge logic. We support including CSS in cn1libs. That specific library doesn't have any CSS but maybe it collided with something and it broke.